# BX Slider and scroll vertical slides

Tags: bxslider

I heave code (bx slider) and somme problem :

```
$('.bxslider-02').bxSlider({
mode: 'vertical', speed: 500, slideMargin:0, infiniteLoop: true, pager: false, controls: true, slideWidth: 276, minSlides: 3, maxSlides: 3, moveSlides: 1, adaptiveHeight: false
});
```

What causes a problem with the altitude change if I have only three slides (no continuation of the carousel). If I have a number of slides 2 and 3 wide only these two. It does not appear at the bottom of another with the number 1.

sample: http://jsfiddle.net/7y9txp23/

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: If I have a set minimum amount of slide 3 and I have 3 slide should not be scrolling. Currently, if I click on the next slide (see slide 2 and 3) the height of the DIV is reduced to two elements, and wanted me to continue to see the third should appear: 2-3-1 (continued carousel) You can set? Alternatively, if there are only 3 elements that should not appear scrolling.

sorry, text from google translate :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your moveslides value is incorrect.

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
mode: 'vertical', speed: 500, slideMargin:0, infiniteLoop: true, pager: false, controls: true, slideWidth: 276, minSlides: 3, maxSlides:4, moveSlides: 3, adaptiveHeight: false
});
```

Check http://jsfiddle.net/k5rut0oy/

**moveSlides**

The number of slides to move on transition. This value must be >= minSlides, and <= maxSlides. If zero (default), the number of fully-visible slides will be used.

With 6 slides:
http://jsfiddle.net/zo4k4aab/

Comment: Yeah you're right. Now it works as it should. Thank you for your help.